# WinApi. ReadFile . Чтение файла, размер которого больше 4 гигов

Tags: winapi

Объясните , пожалуйста, как читать файл больше четырёх гигов через `ReadFile` ( Если можно, то поэтапно, поподробнее, например, какие процессы происходят,  что происходит с полями структуры `OVERLAPPED` `Offset` и `OffsetHigh` ) ?

Comment: Одним куском файл 4гиг прочесть нельзя. Но... допустим вызовите 8 млн раз по 1кбайту - и вы прочтете 8 гиг. OVERLAPPED - не знаю поможет ли вам (разве что если файл по сети читается). Если будет асинхронное чтение - поля Offset  и OffsetHigh будут заполнены верно, на такой размер сумарной разрядности полей (64-битное число) будет достаточно.

Comment: Если вы пишите под х86 то проблема будет не как прочитать, а где хранить. А вычитать 4,8,16 гиг проблемы не вижу. Главное читать не по одному байту (тогда чтение будет ооочень медленным). Куски рекомендую брать от 1кб до 64кб - и проблем не будет. Самый лучший размер - размер кластера в ОС для даного диска (сегодня на современных ПК как правило 8К, и более старые 4к).  Если более 64кб - то нужно искать предельный размер куска, или експерементировать.